# Websphere Commerce Maximum Order Quantity Per Order Change to All Order history and pending

Tags: websphere-commerce

I have here a Websphere commerce 7 Fp 5 Aurora B2B which is using Orgs, contracts and price lists maximum order quantity that we limit each "Store" Org to buy 3 each so that there is enough to go around.  We have 3 sets of entitlements to that most guys Max is 3, better stores max is 5 and a few really good ones max qty is 10.

So we don't have to worry about allocation, these rules let every store buy based on their entitlement.  When they try to put more in the cart then they should, they get a message "You are requesting to order more than your allocation limit.  Please change your requested quantity."  I don't know where this comes from.

Some users buy for 5 or more stores which is selected at checkout during payment.  This keeps those store owners from having to have a bunch of log ins to keep track of.

We recently openned up Order Management, we call it multi-cart because this enables a store owner to create more than 1 cart by going to order management and create a new order.  This makes it much easier for our store owners to manage what they are buying and paying and receiving with out having to call and email our CSR teams.

But now we noticed that some stores are taking advantage of the Multi-cart to buy more that the MAX qty they are allowed.  It wouldn't be so bad, but they are buying all the 1 per customer stuff and all the other stores are calling and complaining because they didn't get their share.  It really isn't fair.

I was thinking of all the different places to add a SQL check of order history and pending orders.  Here is what I cam up with.

1. ATP - Inventory check 
   Pro- best place since customer, sku, entitlement, and everything else pretty much happens here.  It is right up front.
   Con- It doens't have ship-to, so the guys with more than 1 store need to be added as an exception leading sloppy business logic that could change regularly
2. OrderItemAddCmdImpl and overloading ExtendOrderItemProcessCmd
   Pro - Bring ship-to selection up to the front and control everything here.
   Con - Not  certain overhead will like it.
3. At checkout
   Pro - this also will have everything
   Con - I kind of want to reserve this for all payment handling.  It is a little dirty to read throught the order lines and to kick back error with SKU.
4. Have the ERP handle the exception- 
   Con - I realized we are setup that all Orders ship complete, we would have to change this and don't really want to because there are additional credit card penalties for charges less then amount held on credit.

So, the questions are what are your thoughts on additional pros and cons?
Are there other places that I'm missing that would make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We might need to create a new CommandTask and then append it to all existing flows.

OR

As the WebSphere Commerce team to build this new logic into the next release of WebSphere Commerce.

Answer (score 0):

So, for this scenario the answer was creating a JDBC Query that will be called when items are added to cart that sums the Qty by sku of pending orders.

When orderitems are added to the cart, the query will return the item in error if exceeded and not add item.

The query will again run at checkout if all orderitems being paid for exceed total qty max by SKU by shipping address on payment page allowing chance for customer to change billing address if we are limiting item max qty by shipping address.